# How do I use ansible to create IAM users as shown in the documentation?

Tags: ansible

## Setup

I want to use Ansible to configure my IAM users, groups and permissions but I am having trouble even getting off the ground. I installed the development fork of Ansible (2.1.0) and attempted to run the simple play shown in the example in the docs.

## site.yml

```
# Basic user creation example
tasks:
- name: Create two new IAM users with API keys
  iam:
    iam_type: user
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    password: "{{ temp_pass }}"
    access_key_state: create
  with_items:
    - jcleese
    - mpython
```

I ran the play with the following command:

```
$ ansible-playbook site.yml
```

And received the following error:

## Error

```
ERROR! playbooks must be a list of plays

The error appears to have been in '~/aws_kingdom/site.yml': line 2, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

# Basic user creation example
tasks:
^ here
```

I am going to plead ignorance on a lack of understanding of the anatomy of a playbook especially one that should effectively have no hosts since it only applies to creating users in the AWS IAM service.

## References

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/iam_module.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need to tell Ansible what hosts it needs to run on, just that it needs to run locally.

So instead your `site.yml` file should look like:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
  # Basic user creation example
  - name: Create two new IAM users with API keys
    iam:
      iam_type: user
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
      password: "{{ temp_pass }}"
      access_key_state: create
    with_items:
      - jcleese
      - mpython
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That makes sense. I was wondering what to put for a host conceptually since no changes are being made to any hosts but local seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the:

`ERROR! playbooks must be a list of plays`

error myself and after double checking everything couldn't find the error.

By accident I found that when I removed any trailing whitespace and/or newlines from my `playbook.yml` that **it fixed the issue**.

It's weird because I tried validating my YAML with a linter before encountering this fix so I can't understand why it worked.

Admittedly, I don't have much experience with YAML so there might be some rule that I don't understand that I'm missing.